Manifold Book that introduce vector bundle early and uses this approach to go further
I took geometry of manifolds course this semester and my professor started with chapter 1 of Topology from the differentiable viewpoint by John Milnor and then introduced vector bundles and want to teach rest of course on this foundation, it's really hard for me to follow, I think Lee's Smooth manifolds book is great but unfortunately Lee's book is not our reference and it's not aligned with this course, I'll be very grateful if you suggest books that introduce vector bundles early so I can use them to gain more insight, thanks.
edit: this course doesn't have proper lecture note that professor go with it

It might help if you give the actual list of topics in your course.

Loring Tu's book Differential Geometry introduces vector bundles relatively early.

@TedShifrin, thanks for your comments, unfortunately there is no good lecture note for this course.

@Deane, Thanks.

I'll mention a book that others are probably not likely to mention. It is skewed toward differential forms as the main tool, but definitely discusses geometry and vector bundles and connections on them: R.W.R. Darling's Differential Forms and Connections.

I can offer a few suggestions. Of course, the exact textbook that one chooses to use will depend a lot upon your exact lecture course, and personal preferences.

Smooth Manifolds and Fibre Bundles with Applications to Theoretical Physics by Steinar Johannessen - do not be put off by the applications to theoretical physics part, this textbook can be incredibly useful for mathematicians and physicists alike, and it introduces vector bundles early on, and builds the theory up from this.
Bundles, Homotopy, and
Manifolds by Ralph L. Cohen - this textbook is more advanced than the previous suggestion, aimed at graduate students, but it actually begins with vector bundles before defining differential manifolds.

I hope that these suggestions are useful!
